# Authorization .net 5 in serenity framework

Tags: c#, .net, serenity-platform

Can someone show how to get current logged user? And how to chek his permissions, because this doesn't work?

```
var user = (UserDefinition)Authorization.UserDefinition;
if (!Authorization.HasPermission(PermissionKeys.Tenants))
query.Where(fldTenantId == user.TenantId);
```

Thank you!

Comment: https://github.com/serenity-is/Serenity/discussions/5504

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the `Context` object

to get the user id
`Context.User.GetIdentifier()`

to get the user name
`Context.User.Identity.Name`

To get the permissions you can use:
`Context.Permissions` and `Context.Permissions.HasPermission`